# php (pdo) sql, can not set limit and offset

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to do a query setting in the sql the limit and the offset

But all the time I get this error

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''20' OFFSET
>   '0'' at line 8

Here is my code, any idea?

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=".DB_HOST.";dbname=".DB_DB, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $conn->exec("set names utf8"); //BECAUSE I NEED TO WORK WITH CHINESE LANGUAGE
    $limit = 20;
    $offset = 0;
    $params = array(':limit'=>$limit,':offset'=>$offset);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare('
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            dc_user
        WHERE
            user_status != 0
        LIMIT
            :limit
        OFFSET
            :offset
    ');
    $stmt->execute($params);
```

Comment: You can't parametrize `limit`. It adds quotes around the numbers.

Comment: no LIMIT keyword in your query

Comment: @devpro: Yes, there is.

Comment: @juergend actually, [you can](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#limit)